# How to make a couple of async method calls in django2.0

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp, django-2.0

I am a doing a small project and decided to use Django2.0 and python3.6+.

In my django view, I want to call a bunch of REST API and get their results (in any order) and then process my request (saving something to database).

I know the right way to do would be to use `aiohttp` and define an `async` method and await on it.

I am confused about `get_event_loop()` and whether the view method should itself be an async method if it has to `await` the response from these methods.

Also does Django2.0 itself (being implemented in python3.6+) have a loop that I can just add to?

Here is the view I am envisioning

```
from rest_framework import generics
from aiohttp import ClientSession
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    await get_rest_response([url1, url2])

async def fetch(url):
  async with session.get(url) as response:
    return await response.read()

async def get_rest_response(urls):
   async with ClientSession() as session:
      for i in range(urls):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url.format(i), session))
        tasks.append(task)
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: While Django supports all of the versions of Python that include asyncio (3.4+), Django 2.0 does not use asyncio and therefore has no event loop. You may want to take a look at [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can do it by [loop.run_until_complete()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete) call:

```
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_rest_response([url1, url2]))
```

But I doubt if this approach will significantly speed up your code.
Django is a synchronous framework anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of doing but seemed like I am doing this just to be able to call using asyncio. Since your answer is the closest. I will accept the answer.